# Showing $S^1$ is not a retract of $D^2$ using homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'd like to know if my argument below, in which I try to show that the 1-sphere is not a retract of the 2-disk using homotopy, is valid.

Suppose there is a retract $r:D^2 \to S^1$.  Then we can consider the induced homomorphism $r_\ast:\pi_1(D^2,x_0) \to \pi_1(S^1,x_0)$, where the basepoint $x_0 \in S^1 \subset D^2$.  Let $[f] \in \pi_1(D^2,x_0)$, where $f:I \to D^2$ maps $I$ to $S^1 \subset D^2$.  Now we have $r_\ast[f]=[rf] \in \pi_1(S^1,x_0)$.  Since $r$ fixes $S^1$, it follows that $r_\ast[f]$ is nontrivial.  But $\pi_1(D^2,x_0)=0$ and $\pi_1(S^1,x_0)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, so there cannot be a retract $r:D^2 \to S^1$.

Does this work?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it works. See also Massey's "Algebraic topology: An introduction".

Comment: Great, thanks.$\,$

Comment: Why must $r_*[f]$ be non-trivial? Unless of course you meant to say that $f$ has non-zero degree when the codomain is restricted to $S^1$, but you need to state this in order for the proof to work.

Comment: @DanielRust  Yes, I meant for the image of $f$ to be a nontrivial closed path in $S^1 \subset D^2$.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, we can get past needing to use explicit elements of the fundamental group by using the 'composition' definition of a retract. The map $r\colon X\to A$ is a retract for the subspace $A\subset X$ if $r\circ i=\mbox{Id}_A$ where $i\colon A\to X$ is the inclusion map.

Now, suppose there is a retract $r\colon D^2\to S^1$, then $r\circ i=\mbox{Id}_{S^1}$ and so $r_*\circ i_*={\mbox{Id}_{S^1}}_*$ by the functorality of $\pi_1$. Also by functorality, we know that ${\mbox{Id}_{S^1}}_*=\mbox{Id}_{\pi_1(S^1)}$ but note that we have $r_*\colon 1\to \mathbb{Z}$ which must be the trivial map and so $r_*\circ i_*$ must also be the trivial map. The identity map on $\pi_1(S^1)$ is not the trivial map because $\pi_1(S^1)$ is not trivial - contradiction.