# Is there any continuous map from $D^2$ to annuli such that it fixes the boundary?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity

I wonder if there is any continuous map
$$f: D^2\to D^2\bigg\backslash \left\{\mathrm{int}\ D^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\}\simeq \Bbb S^1\times [0,1]$$
such that $f|_{\partial D^2}=\mathrm{Id}$?

I don't know how to deal with these type of problems in general. I can't imagine (*and is impossible in practice*) about such maps and probably there is no such map. I think if there is any, it should be surjective then a quotient map but the **boundary condition** does not allow me to use any argument. Any nice idea for this and similar problems (about is there any continuous map ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the boundary circle in the annuli $\simeq S^1\times \{1\}\simeq S^1$ is not contractible in $S^1\times [0,1]$, and the map $f$ would be its null-homotopy.

More formally, consider a map $g$ from the annuli to the circle, $(x, t)\in S^1\times [0,1] \mapsto (x,1)$. This is continuous. So then $g\circ f$ would be a retraction of a disc into it's boundary sphere. You can find many proofs that this is impossible, such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809028/showing-s1-is-not-a-retract-of-d2-using-homotopy).